# how to set the boundaries of the map? uses OSMDroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

OSMDroid

how to set the boundaries of the map? so that there's such a

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
mMapView.setScrollableAreaLimit(boundingBox)
```